# The Riddle - I Could be Used in Many Ways

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

> In whole, you may use me in the measuring.
>
> With my $1^{st}$ & $2^{nd}$ part, you may use me in the coloring.
>
> With my $2^{nd}$ & $3^{rd}$ part, you may use me in the casting.
>
> With my $3^{rd}$ & $4^{th}$ part, you may use me in the integrating.
>
> With my $4^{th}$ & $5^{th}$ part, you may use me in the displaying.
>
> With my $5^{th}$ & $6^{th}$ part, you may use me in the lighting.

Who/What am I?

Hint 1:

> For functions in each clause:
>
>  **measuring** -> for the projection
>  **coloring** -> for the decoration
>  **casting** -> for the hardness
>  **integrating** -> for the conduction
>  **displaying** -> for the monitor
>  **lighting** -> for the attraction

Hint 2:

> Add ***Knowledge*** tag

Hint 3:

> All the parts mentioned in clauses has the same length

Comment: lightening or lighting?

Comment: @none Hmm, I think both are OK, just less meaning difference :)

Comment: Hmm, think a bit, I changed to the "lighting" to avoid interpreted as "lose weight".

Comment: [you're such an inspiring user!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89785/hope-youre-happy-in-this)

Comment: It's my pleasure :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm almost certain the answer is

> **cosine**

In whole, you may use me in the measuring.

> If $\theta$ is the angle measured counterclockwise from the $x$-axis along the arc of the unit circle then $\cos \theta$ is the horizontal coordinate of the arc endpoint, i.e, the length of the projection of the radius onto the horizontal axis.

With my 1st & 2nd part, you may use me in the coloring.

> **Co** - the chemical symbol for cobalt, which is used in pigments such as cobalt blue, cerulean clue and cobalt green.

With my 2nd & 3rd part, you may use me in the casting.

> **Os** - the chemical symbol for Osmium. Manufacturers use its alloys with platinum, iridium, and other platinum-group metals in applications that require extreme durability and hardness.

With my 3rd & 4th part, you may use me in the integrating.

> **Si** - the chemical symbol for Silicon, which is used heavily in integrated electric circuits.

With my 4th & 5th part, you may use me in the displaying.

> **In** - the checmical symbol for Indium. The primary consumption of indium worldwide is LCD production.

With my 5th & 6th part, you may use me in the lighting.

> **Ne** - the chemical symbol for Neon, which is often used in signs and produces an unmistakable bright reddish-orange light.

Comment: You are a step closer to the chemists :P