# Hope You're Happy in This!

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Inspired by [The Riddle - I Could be Used in Many Ways](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89768/the-riddle-i-could-be-used-in-many-ways) by Conifers :D

> My whole is usually shown in a tree.
>   About my $1^{st}$ and $2^{nd}$ parts is fond.
>   About my $2^{nd}$ and $3^{rd}$ parts, PNGs.
>   About my $3^{rd}$ and $4^{th}$ parts, opal.
>   About my $4^{th}$ and $5^{th}$ parts, moot.
>   Right before my $5^{th}$ and $6^{th}$ parts is a yard.

Comment: Just wanna make sure I get the rules of this riddle right. If the word is "abcdef", the 1st part would be something like "ab" and the 2nd one "bc", is this correct? I also assume they don't have to overlap or be of equal length.

Comment: @greysaff yes, the parts don't overlap.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Relationship

Divided into six parts as follows

> Re, la, ti, on, sh, ip

My whole is usually shown in a tree.

> Family tree

About my 1st and 2nd parts is fond.

> Fo**rela**nd - a landform projecting into the sea

About my 2nd and 3rd parts, PNGs.

> P**lati**ngs - surface coverings in which a metal is deposited on a conductive surface.

About my 3rd and 4th parts, opal.

> Op**tion**al

About my 4th and 5th parts, moot.

> Mo**onsh**ot - home run that travels a great distance vertically

Right before my 5th and 6th parts is a yard.

> **Ship**yard - my thinking is that this clue is clued the wrong way round as it fits so perfectly otherwise.

Note

> I have leaned heavily on the wordplay aspect where "about" is a wordplay clue.